# Boot warning "No packages marked for update" Centos 7

Tags: centos

I recently installed CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003. And a message started to appear at boot as well "No packages marked for update".
I already looked in the settings of yum, you don't have the yum-cron package installed.
There is nothing in the / etc / inittab file / /etc/rc.d/init.d
Where can I disable this search for updates?

Comment: Check your log to see what logged it.

Comment: there's nothing in the logs.